# Connecting two nodes with line to close segment in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, polyline-creation, vertices

I have a line that I drew where the ends are not connected. I now want to select the two end nodes and hit a button to have QGIS connect them with a line segment. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activate **Snapping** (Settings --> Snapping options...). Select required snapping mode and set at least *Snap to* (To vertext for your case) and some *Tolerance* value.

Than just edit layer and draw new line segment connecting two nodes. Now when you move cursor close enough to node when drawing line, the line will snap to the node (showing you the pink cross). Distance of snap is depend on *Tolerance* value.

For more information about snapping see 
[QGIS User Guide](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#setting-the-snapping-tolerance-and-search-radius)

note: You can't snap to nodes which are just being drawn. It works only for already drawn features.

[image: Snapping options]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In newer QGIS versions, you can automatically close a line using [Geometry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) with this expression:

`close_line ($geometry)`

*Expression (here with Geometry Generator for visalization): red=initial line; balck= line created by the expression:*
[image]